# Search for strings broken

Tags: support

Searching for strings is broken. A string like "me too" returns posts that contain "me", "too", and "me too".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is intentional, the default search operator for Stack Exchange sites is `OR` (not `AND`).  Also, the default search result screen is *relevance*, so ones matching more terms will be presented up top, with additional posts you may be interested in listed below.

Additionally, by default we roll up to **showing questions**, so the match for ["me too"](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=%22me%20too%22) (if you are using quotes) may be in an answer.

If you wish to search that *exact* string, you should use [`"me too"`](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=%22me%20too%22) (with quotes) to get exact matches only.  Or, if you want all the terms, but not necessarily together, use `+`, like [`+me +too`](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=%2bme%20%2btoo&submit=search).

For more info, [see the search help/options](https://askubuntu.com/search).

Comment: I **was** using quotes, but indeed I should have added `is:answer`. :)

Answer (score 2):

This has been the case for a while (at least a few weeks). In a pinch, you can add a `title:` or `body:` qualifier and it seems to work. Something like

http://meta.askubuntu.com/search?q=body%3A%22me+too%22&submit=search

Comment: Yay, thanks for the tip!